# questions on random selection based on given weight vector

Tags: java, algorithm, random, weka, sample

I am reading the weka implementation on re-sampling an array based on a given weight vector. After reading through the code, I am not sure what’s the algorithm underlying this implementation. In addition, I am quite confusing on the usage of these two lines of code:

```
  Utils.normalize(probabilities, sumProbs / sumOfWeights);
```

and

```
// Make sure that rounding errors don't mess things up
probabilities[numInstances() - 1] = sumOfWeights;
```

I do not know what they are used for. The following is the code copied from Weka

```
Instances weka::core::Instances::resampleWithWeights(Random random,double[] weights )       
{

if (weights.length != numInstances()) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("weights.length != numInstances.");
}
Instances newData = new Instances(this, numInstances());
if (numInstances() == 0) {
  return newData;
}
double[] probabilities = new double[numInstances()];
double sumProbs = 0, sumOfWeights = Utils.sum(weights);
for (int i = 0; i < numInstances(); i++) {
  sumProbs += random.nextDouble();
  probabilities[i] = sumProbs;
}
Utils.normalize(probabilities, sumProbs / sumOfWeights);

// Make sure that rounding errors don't mess things up
probabilities[numInstances() - 1] = sumOfWeights;
int k = 0; int l = 0;
sumProbs = 0;
while ((k < numInstances() && (l < numInstances()))) {
  if (weights[l] < 0) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Weights have to be positive.");
  }
  sumProbs += weights[l];
  while ((k < numInstances()) &&
       (probabilities[k] <= sumProbs)) { 
  newData.add(instance(l));
  newData.instance(k).setWeight(1);
  k++;
  }
  l++;
}
return newData;
```

}

Comment: It looks like some C++ has leaked over into your Java. Shouldn't `weka::core::Instances::resampleWithWeights` be `weka.core.Instances.resampleWithWeights`?

Comment: What is Weka?  Could you link us to the article in question?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - Just look at the [tag wiki for Weka](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/weka/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code fragment:

```
Utils.normalize(probabilities, sumProbs / sumOfWeights);
```

just divides each element of `probabilities` by the second argument. This converts `probabilities` from an array that has maximum element of `sumProbs` to one that has a maximum element of `sumOfWeights`. The second piece of code:

```
probabilities[numInstances() - 1] = sumOfWeights;
```

just ensures that the last (maximum) element actually is `sumOfWeights` and wasn't thrown off by some sort of rounding error.

**EDIT** Here's the theory about how the entire method works. The first half (up to the declaration of `k` and `l`) generates `probabilities` as a vector of (not independent) random numbers that are increasing and the last of which is the sum of weights. This is a random partition of the interval [0, sumOfWeights]. Now the weights themselves are a partition of the same interval. Implicitly, each existing instance is assigned to one each element of the weight-based partition.

The second half of the method simply steps along the weights partition (using index `l`). It samples the `l`<sup>th</sup> instance as many times as the random partition falls in the indicated weight partition. I realize that this explanation is a little awkwardly worded. Perhaps a picture of what's going on will help:

```
0                                                   sumOfWeights
↓                                                       ↓

|     *   *         *       *               * *     *   * ← Random partition
|    ^      ^           ^      ^     ^     ^         ^  ^ ← Weights partition

   0     2        1        1       0     0       3     1  ← # of samples
```

The second half of the method simply counts how many random partition boundaries (denoted by `*`) are in each weight interval (bounded by `^`). A little consideration should convince you that this is a valid method of randomly sampling with replacement according to the given weights.

Comment: can you elaborate what the underlying algorithm is for this implementation? I guess it should be some established algorithm. But I don't know which is it.

Comment: @user288609 - I added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Ted, I appreciate your help in explaining this. is there a name for this algorithm/heuristic? Thanks

Comment: @user288609 - There probably is a name, but I don't know what it's called.